# Adding delay between Observable Items RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I have an observable I've created from a list of objects. For each object in the list I make a network request but I'd like to put a delay between each item in the list as to space out the requests a bit. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
return Observable.from(documentGroupModels).flatMap(new Func1<DocumentGroupModel, Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(DocumentGroupModel documentGroupModel) {
            return refreshDocumentWithUri(documentGroupModel.getUri(), documentGroupModel.sectionGroupId,
                                          includeExceptions, false);
        }
    });
```

Using delay or buffer doesn't quite work for this scenario as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of **Zip** and **interval** operator if your delay is static, so you can emit an item of your zip every time configure on your interval.

Check the example

```
       @Test
public void delaySteps() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Subscription subscription =
            Observable.zip(Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)), Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                           (i, t) -> i)
                    .subscribe(n -> System.out.println("time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Also you can create an Observable with your list and use **concatMap**, then you can use **delay** for every item emitted. Maybe this solution is more elegant and no so Hacky

```
      @Test
public void delayObservableList() {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .concatMap(s -> Observable.just(s).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .subscribe(n -> System.out.println(n + " emitted"),
                       e -> {
                       },
                       () -> System.out.println("All emitted"));
    new TestSubscriber().awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

You can see another examples of delay here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableDelay.java

Comment: I went with the second solution, works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `delay' operator e.g.

```
return Observable.from(documentGroupModels).flatMap(new Func1<DocumentGroupModel, Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(DocumentGroupModel documentGroupModel) {
            return refreshDocumentWithUri(documentGroupModel.getUri(), documentGroupModel.sectionGroupId,
                                          includeExceptions, false).delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't delay each item, it just pushes everything forward 2 seconds.

Comment: Strange. It's essentially the same as the second solution except it uses most of your own code and flatMap (concatMap is better). See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012715/rxjava-delay-how-to-get-variable-delay-on-each-item-emitted-from-a-list).